# Batch file breaks when calling a file from any other drive other than your main OS drive

Tags: batch-file, directory

First post so be gentle. I have a batch file I've created that essentially takes any image or pdf dragged onto it, runs it through a converter program (depending on file extension), renames it, and then runs our custom uploader program to load it into our system.

This seems to work with any file dragged from your main Operating System hard hard drive but when dragged from any other drive (either a local drive or mapped network drive e.t.c.) it breaks and gives me an error saying "the system cannot find the specified file"

**What tweak do I need to make?**

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
@echo off

set libpath=%~p0

set filename=%1
set fileext=%~x1

IF /I %fileext%==.jpg GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.eps GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.psd GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.png GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.gif GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.tif GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.bmp GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.tiff GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.jpeg GOTO ConvertIMAGE
IF /I %fileext%==.pdf GOTO ConvertPDF
GOTO ErrorMessage

:ConvertIMAGE
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TotalImageConverter\ImageConverter.exe" "%filename%" "%cd%" -s1800x1800 -o ue -c tif ext tif tc auto log c:\TIFFlog.txt -verbosity detail 
call set filename=%%filename:%fileext%=.tif%%
Goto UploadImage

:ConvertPDF
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CoolUtils\Total PDF Converter\PDFConverter.exe" "%filename%" "%cd%" -c tif ext tif tc JPEG 
call set filename=%%filename:%fileext%=.tif%%
Goto UploadImage

:ErrorMessage
echo Not A Valid File Type
Pause

GOTO SkipUpload

:UploadImage

set d=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
set d=%d: =_%
set t=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set t=%t: =0%
set stampedfilename=hXXXXXX.%d%-%t%___C7451F.tif
rename %filename% %stampedfilename%

call "%libpath%nametif.bat" %stampedfilename%

chdir C:\KLS\Uploader

call upload.bat

:SkipUpload
```

**EDIT: Adding in additional called Batch Files**

Here is nametif.bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set tifpath=C:\KLS\hardcopy\

set libpath=%~p0

REM set filename=HXXXXXX.20110111-152930___ACA51F.TIF
set filename=%~n1%~x1
set fileext=%~x1
set filepath=%~p1
echo.%filename%

start /w wscript.exe "%libpath%inputhawb.vbs"
call "%libpath%~userin.bat"
del "%libpath%~userin.bat"
set hawb=%USERIN%
REM set hawb=1234567
echo.%hawb%

set filename=%filename:~0,-13%
set filename=%filename:XXXXXX=!hawb!%%fileext%
set filename=%filename:H=h%
set filename=%filename:TIF=tif%
echo.%filename%

rename %1 %filename%
move "%filepath%%filename%" "%tifpath%"
echo %tifpath%
```

Here is the inputhawb.vbs file that nametif.bat calls

```
strUserIn = InputBox("Enter Hawb") 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
strFileName = fs.BuildPath(Wscript.ScriptFullName & "\..", "~userin.bat") 
strFileName = fs.GetAbsolutePathName(strFileName) 
Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 2, True) 
ts.WriteLine "set userin=" & strUserIn 
ts.Close
```

The upload.bat file is just a pretty generic call to a .jar uploading platform using java.

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP GUYS!

Comment: `chdir C:\KLS\Uploader` --> `chdir /D "C:\KLS\Uploader"`. In general, you should put quotes `""` around all file/dir. paths as they might contain white-spaces or other special characters that may harm otherwise. At which point does the script "break"? Please remove `@echo off` (temporarily) for debugging...

Comment: without knowing quite what the parameters to the converter executables do, and without `nametif.bat` and `uploader.bat`, we're guessing.Possibly the `rename` command has the original file's drivename and the converters are processing to `%cd%` which would probably be the OS drive.

Comment: @aschipfl As `CD` takes only one path it doesn't care if the path is quoted or not. Another special case for CMD.

Comment: @Noodles, that is only true when it comes to white-spaces (or other token separators), but not if it comes to special characters like `^` or `&`, for instance, where quotation is mandatory (or proper escaping, but this is more complicated and quite confusing for newbies); that is why I prefer recommending quotation of paths in general (although the example path in the question does not contain any of such said characters)...

Comment: **Added additional batch file code!**